# Adjust the hardness of the blur effect in iOS 8

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, blur

I am using the blur effect on an image view in iOS 8 and I wonder if it's possible to tell swift how strong the blur effect should be.

This is the code..

```
    var blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect) as UIVisualEffectView
    visualEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds

    imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is not possible to do so, you could change the alpha level of the blur view itself but that is going to give you a warning about graphical errors and might not always work perfectly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/

> Setting the Correct Alpha Value
>
> When using the UIVisualEffectView class, avoid alpha values that are
>   less than 1. Creating views that are partially transparent causes the
>   system to combine the view and all the associated subviews during an
>   offscreen render pass. UIVisualEffectView objects need to be combined
>   as part of the content they are layered on top of in order to look
>   correct. Setting the alpha to less than 1 on the visual effect view or
>   any of its superviews causes many effects to look incorrect or not
>   show up at all.

The best solution I know of is to use something like [FxBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) where you can change the "blurRadius" for the effect you are requesting. It seems like nothing is better performance wise than apples implementation, but 3rd party libraries will suffice as long as you are not planning on manipulating the bounds of the blur view while animating.